My httpOnly cookie login is not working on mobile but it does on desktop
I have an auth system like this:
/login --> I pass username and password, and I get back the token in the httpOnly cookie.
Then, for each subsequent request, I use credentials: 'include' with fetch. That all works perfectly fine in desktop.
However, when using Safari or Chrome on my phone, the login is successful but it's either not storing the httpOnly cookie or not sending in subsequent requests.
Btw the API is deployed in another host, so we use SameSite: None when setting the cookie in the backend. Both hosts use HTTPS, so secure is on.
Is this a common problem? Backend is .NET btw, front is React.
